# How to have a div that acts like iframe?

Tags: css, html, iframe

**HTML**

```
<div class="myFrame"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.myFrame {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    URL: "http://google.com";
}
```

How can I make this without having iframe.

Comment: Better idea: tell us why you don't want to use an `iframe` (a block container that loads the content of another page) instead of why you want to create your own block container that loads the content of another page.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem.

Comment: I am running a node program that collects data from a site, this data is posted onto an html page, I dont want users to directly see this html page so I am trying to mask it by a different URL. If users are able to see the original html page, they know where to access simple user information which I cant have.

Comment: This now sounds like an X/Y/Z problem :P Seriously, if you are going to ask a security question, ask a security question.

Comment: It's impossible to hide the location of the original page. It doesn't matter if you use an iframe or jQuery, somewhere in the source of your mask page, the location will be visible.

Comment: I agree with @Stijn, you cannot hide the original location.

Comment: A URL is an address. Imagine you want to send someone mail, but you don't want _anyone_ to be able to read the address you're sending it to. Well, what do you do? Presumably it's easy enough to come up with a code, but are you going to teach it to the Post Office? How secure is that, really? So do you use some alternate mail service? Deliver it yourself? No, you just stop worrying and write the address on there normally. Skip the slippery slope and secure the actual access, instead of relying on [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to have a div that acts like iframe?

You don't. Seriously - if you want an iframe, use an iframe. If you don't - don't. Something that mimics an iframe cannot be any better than an iframe.

### But I don't want to give users the URL

You think a div's going to help? What you're trying to ask is:

### How do I hide data?

So you have page A which needs information from page B. No matter what you do on the client side, the user  can know where page B is. It is impossible to both download the location of page B, and not download the location of page B. What you really want is a file that is below the webroot - one that is inaccessible for the public. But how do you include it in page A? You do it server-side. Page A will have to authenticate the action, then return the *contents* of page B. Nowhere in the process will you disclose the actual location of page B, and it is best practice to have page B plain **inaccessible**.

Comment: +1 to inaccessible. The right way to do this is to password-protect that URL or something, if I understand the OP's use case correctly. It should be administrative access only, login required.

Answer (score -2):

you could do the following.

```
<div id="myFrame"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenPage(url)   
    { 
        $.get(url, function(response)   
        {
            $('#myFrame').html(response);   
        });
    }
</script>   
<a href="#" onclick="OpenPage('anotherPage.html');">Go to my other page..</a>

CSS:
div.myFrame {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    URL: "http://google.com";
}
```

curious, why would you want to use a `DIV` as an `iFrame`?

also, this [**LINK**](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/298316-div-working-like-an-iframe/) will provide you with more information if needed, and alternative ways to accomplish this.

Comment: -1 for jQuery (this question does not have a jQuery tag) and certain tags (such as html, body, title, etc.) may cause problems.